# Calling truss from python program

Tags: python, subprocess, truss

I have a python program where i want to run a BSD system command with truss so that I can get a list of the syscalls made (open, stat, etc). For example, the command would be :

```
truss -S <application specific command>
```

I am using subprocess.Popen(command, .., ..) to call the command. I am passing the command as a list, and not a string, so i get proper encoding from Python. So the command list is like below :

```
command = ['truss', '-S', <application specific command>]
```

But this gives an error for truss :

```
truss -S "ls -lrt"
truss: execvp  No such file or directory
truss: can not get etype: No such process
```

But if I run the same command without the quotes above, it goes through. Python adds quotes similar to above when I pass the command as a list to Popen, and I need that for the commands to work as expected.

What the best way to solve this ?

Comment: First, you can run your python script under `truss` and see what args are getting passed to `execvp`.  Perhaps you need the full path?

Comment: It seems that either subprocess cannot find truss or truss cannot find ls. Try to use full path for truss and see if that helps any